# Pin UIView to top of screen when keyboard slides up

Tags: ios, swift

I've got the following UIView Layout for a simple chat to the left and I'm shifting the screen content up by the size of the keyboard, when the keyboard shows up, like shown to the right.

```swift
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 { self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height }
        }
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is to pin the upper part of my layout (i.e. the user profilepic, username, onine / offline indicator) to the screen, so that it stays in pace and only the UITableView get shifted up by the size of the keyboard.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: make the upper view as navigation bar. so it will stay.

Comment: upper view give it fix height and pin its top Anchor .. for table .. give it lessThanAndEquallTo constraint ... this will help you ...

Answer (score 0):

You are able to move your message content (bottom view) and decrease the height of your tableView the amount equal to keyboard height.

More detail, you constraint your message content and assign to `bottomConstraint`, your table height constraint is `heightConstraint`. When keyboard shows, decrease `bottomConstraint` and `heightConstraint` by the keyboard height; revert when keyboard hides.

Hope this will be helpful.